# References to SGA 8 and descent theory

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, descent, geometric-invariant-theory

In Geometric Invariant Theory, by Mumford, Fogarty, and Kirwan, if there is a mention of descent theory, it almost always comes along with a reference to SGA 8, Theorem 5.2 (see the end of the proof of prop 6.9 on page 119, for example).  Now I know SGA 8 was never made, but I was wondering:

1. Does anyone have a good guess as to what this theorem should say?
2. Does anyone have a good reference for a quick and "hands off" introduction to descent theory?  I am really just looking to understand the "gist" of it.

Comment: I wouldn't call this a quick introduction, but look at FGA, or FGA Explained (http://www.amazon.com/Fundamental-Algebraic-Geometry-Mathematical-Monographs/dp/0821842455/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1325953638&sr=8-1)


Comment: You can also look at his *Technique de descente et théorèmes d'existence en géométrie algébrique*, Parts I,II available on Numdam.org

Comment: Actually, what Mumford cites as SGA 8 is what we nowadays call SGA 1, chapter VIII.

Comment: You should post that as an answer, a-fortiori.

Comment: SGA8 is mentioned as LNM 407:
Cohomologie cristalline des schémas de caractéristique P.Berthelot 

(See the bibliography on p.41, 43 on "Applications of Sheaves" LNM 753)

But LNM 407 isnt about descent theory (only a little, no in the sense that Mumford book ask).

I guess that "Le methode de la descente" by J. Giraud , Memoire del SMF , n2, 1964, could be a useful reference, is very hard for a no lover of category theory. This was the old central work about descente theory, and was the J. Giraud thesis did  under Grothendieck (as professor).  

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For question 1, see the comment above.

Collecting the answers to question 2:

- Grothendieck's original *FGA*, starting with [TDTE I](http://www.numdam.org/numdam-bin/fitem?id=SB_1958-1960__5__299_0)
- Vistoli's chapter in *FGA explained*, for the connection with stacks
- [What is descent theory?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/22032/what-is-descent-theory) for a very short overview
- Bosch-Lütkebohmert-Raynaud, *Néron Models* (recommended by BCnrd in the above-mentioned thread)
- Waterhouse, *Introduction to Affine Group Schemes*, containing a 20-page introduction primarily concerned with the affine case

"Community wiki" post, feel free to modify.